# Why is gestureRecognizerShouldBegin called multiple times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gesture

I made gesture like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]     
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnPhoto:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;                                              
tapGesture.delegate = self;
[self.htmlWebView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

And when tap on **htmlWebView**  call **gestureRecognizerShouldBegin** for several time.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]){
        [self performSelector:@selector(tapOnPhoto:) withObject:gestureRecognizer];

    }
    return YES;
}
```

Why is gestureRecognizerShouldBegin called more than once per gesture?

Comment: try this :  tapGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;

Answer (score 0):

As per the 
[gestureRecognizerShouldBegin](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624213-gesturerecognizershouldbegin?language=objc) description.

> This method is called when a gesture recognizer attempts to transition
>   out of the UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible state. Returning NO causes
>   the gesture recognizer to transition to the
>   UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed state.

This method will get called multiple times to get the transition state of gesture.

Also as you have added a selector for TapGesture why are you calling that method explicitly, the method will get called itself.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]){
        [self performSelector:@selector(tapOnPhoto:) withObject:gestureRecognizer];

    }
    return YES;
}
```

There will be no need of this function you can remove it as you are calling only a method there.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rajat mentioned in his answer you can remove the delegate method and instead use your `tapOnPhoto:` method to parse your gesture logic.

The `UIGestureRecognizer` object that you'll receive as the argument into that method has a property called `state`

Which might have the following values:

```
UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible
UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan
UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged
UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled
UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed
UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized
```

You can use a `switch`and provide specific logic for each case.